# Exclude host machine from charles proxy recordings

Tags: android, macos, charles-proxy

I'm trying to capture results from an Android device only, but I keep seeing results from my MAC as well.

I've tried excluding 127.0.0.1 and the address for the HTTP proxy (from Help>Install Charles Root Certificate on a Mobile Device) in recording settings.

I've also looked up the ip address for the phone and enabled only it in SSL Proxying Settings (instead of *.*)

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You should turn off this option in the Charles app:

**Proxy > macOS Proxy**

2) You can also check that the network adapter you are using does not have a proxy configured:

**System Preferences > Network >** mark the first connected adapter from the list on the left, e.g.: **Wi-Fi** and click the **Advanced...** button > make sure that there is no proxy configured on the **Proxies** tab

If you see that the localhost is set as proxy, clear the settings: [image]

The first method does the same as the second one, but sometimes the Charles app does not remove properly proxy settings from the network adapter, so you must delete it manually.

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem you have is that too many requests make it difficult to find the ones you want to work with you can use the "**Focus**" option by right-clicking on a request you want to monitor in the requests pane and select **Focus**. Note that you can focus on multiple hosts.

This will make request from other hosts get grouped under a "Other hosts" entry in the requests pane, so they won't disturb your work anymore.